# Setting the Value of a Custom Field in Acumatica 2019 R1

Tags: acumatica

I am in the process of upgrading from Acumatica 2018 R2 to 2019 R1. In quite a few of my customizations, I have code, triggered by a button click or an event handler, which sets/changes the value of a custom field. That was working as expected in 2018 R2. However, in 2019 R1 the values on the custom fields are not being updated. Here's a simple example.

```
public class SOOrderEntry_SOOpenPOsGILink_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    protected virtual void SOLine_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        SOLine row = (SOLine)e.Row;
        if (row != null)
        {
            bool isEmpty = true;
            SOLineExt ext = row.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();

            // logic determining value of isEmpty

            ext.UsrEnableOpenPOs = isEmpty;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `UsrEnableOpenPOs` is defined as folows.

```
public class SOLineExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine>
{
    #region UsrEnableOpenPOs
    [PXBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="EnableOpenPOs", Enabled = false, Visible=false)]
    [PXUnboundDefault(false, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]

    public virtual bool? UsrEnableOpenPOs { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrEnableOpenPOs : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<usrEnableOpenPOs> { }
    #endregion
}
```

In this example, when a SOLine is selected on the SO Order Entry screen, the value of `SOLineExt.UsrEnableOpenPOs` should be set to the value of `isEmpty`. This code works in 2018 R2 and correctly updates `UsrEnableOpenPOs`. However, in 2019 R1, the code is triggered correctly and runs, but the value on the screen is not updated.

As I mentioned, we have quite a few instances where we are running into this problem. In some cases the code is triggered by a button click and in other cases by different events like RowSelected, RowInserting, FieldUpdated and RowUpdated.

I would appreciate some insight on why this code is no longer working and what I can do to fix it.

Comment: you try to set the value via cache when you can vs just setting the row object. Such as sender.SetValueExt<SOLineExt.usrEnableOpenPOs>(row, isEmptry);

Comment: @Brendan Thanks! That works! When I use that with the RowSelected event, however, I get an Acuminator warning "A DAC instance passed to the RowSelected event handler cannot be modified inside this event handler." Should I worry about that or is that fine?

Comment: unbound fields should be set in the RowSelecting event or FieldSelecting event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should always try to set the value in cache vs the row instance.

ex:

```
sender.SetValueExt<SOLineExt.usrEnableOpenPOs>(row, isEmptry);
```

Unbound fields should be set in the RowSelecting or FieldSelecting events. The RowSelected event should be for UI changes such as disabled, visible, etc. fields.